# assigning to array at different times yields different results

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-2017

I have these two different codes that are very slightly different but yield different results:

```
(async () => {
  const results = new Array(concurrentBrowsers).fill({});
  const browsers = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < concurrentBrowsers; index++) {
    browsers.push(
      (async function() {
        let i = index;
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless });
        const page = await getNewPage({ browser });
        results[i].loginPage = await timer(actions.loginPage, { page }); // <---- this line
        results[i].homePage = await timer(actions.homePage, {
          page,
          username,
          password
        });
        console.log(i, results[i]);
        browser.close();
      })()
    );
  }
  await Promise.all(browsers);
})();
```

Which results in

```
1 { loginPage: 2.924, homePage: 19.939 }
2 { loginPage: 2.924, homePage: 21.388 }
3 { loginPage: 2.924, homePage: 21.122 }
0 { loginPage: 2.924, homePage: 21.305 }
4 { loginPage: 2.924, homePage: 21.6 }
```

And another one:

```
(async () => {
  const results = new Array(concurrentBrowsers).fill({});
  const browsers = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < concurrentBrowsers; index++) {
    browsers.push(
      (async function() {
        let i = index;
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless });
        const page = await getNewPage({ browser });
        let loginPageTime = await timer(actions.loginPage, { page }); // <---- this line
        let homePageTime = await timer(actions.homePage, {
          page,
          username,
          password
        });
        results[i].loginPage = loginPageTime;
        results[i].homePage = homePageTime;
        console.log(i, results[i]);
        browser.close();
      })()
    );
  }
  await Promise.all(browsers);
})();
```

Which results in

```
2 { loginPage: 3.291, homePage: 17.911 }
4 { loginPage: 3.226, homePage: 18.949 }
1 { loginPage: 3.047, homePage: 22.619 }
0 { loginPage: 3.291, homePage: 24.508 }
3 { loginPage: 3.059, homePage: 26.391 }
```

The first code has a bug in it, it seems that the `loginPage` result is always taken from the last iteration and as you can see is set to the same value in all iterations.

The only difference is that I assign the result of timer  in the first example to `results[i].loginPage` and in the second example to `loginPageTime`.

Can someone please explain this difference ?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, async functions are an *ES2017* feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, both code variants share a same problem, but the second code block does not show what is going wrong:

```
const results = new Array(concurrentBrowsers).fill({});
```

This creates *one*(!) empty object and assigns it to *all* array entries. Whatever you change to that object will be seen via all array entries, as they all reference the same object.

The reason that you see the inconsistency happening in the first version, is that there are other assignments happening between the two `await` expressions that are in the same iteration, while the second code version does not make the assignment until right before the `console.log`.

You can perform a correct initialisation of `results` as follows:

```
const results = Array.from(new Array(concurrentBrowsers), _ => ({}));
```

Comment: @Michael It's the same object in every array item..  eg.. it's like if you did this..   `var a = {x:1}, b = a; b.y = 2;`   both a & b would equal  `{x:1,y:2}`  IOW: objects in javascript are reference based, and when you do `a = b` your copying the reference, not it's values.

Comment: @Keith If that's the case, why is loginPage the same but homePage isn't?

Comment: @Bob  Because the requests are async, and placed inside of a Promise.All,..  And then he's console logging as he goes, it's a timing thing.  His results are all going to be dependent on when the promises are resolved..  If he did a `console.log(results)` after his Promise.all you would see all the values the same.

Comment: @trincot that's clever and was indeed the problem. I still don't understand though why the results were different in the two cases

Comment: Maybe it helps to understand if in the first version of the code (with the problematic `results` initialisation) you place a `console.log(i, results[i])` between the two awaits: you'll then notice that that logged value is in general not the same as the output you get from the `console.log` that follows a few lines below (for the same *i*). This is because the second `await` will allow other promises to resolve and also assign to `loginPage`, which will *overwrite* the value that you had just logged.